# Azimuth on projected tile map

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, azimuth, reprojection-mathematics

Here is a very specific problem :

I have some mercator flight simulator maps I projected with real coordinates. However, due to game simplification, these maps are not oriented correctly and real bearings don't correspond to ingame ones.

In the following map, **arrows show the ingame North (0°)** and the **number indicates the projected real azimuth**.
[image]

But my flight plan tool need to display ingame bearings to be accurate and useful !

So, is there a way, or a mathematic function allowing me to recalculate ingame bearings from the map projection, when the figure is in the map bounding box ?

I have the WGS84 coordinates of the 4 corners, and maps are always perfectly oriented NSEW ingame.

I can imagine there could be some maths in the solution.

Comment: Is your map above in Mercator? Do the WGS84 corners of the in-game maps make a perfect rectangle/square?

Comment: World Map is WebMercator. The ingame map is always a perfect rectangle, with an ingame North/South alignment.

Comment: how are you calculating the azimuths?

Comment: var getAzimuth = function(a, b) {
    let dx = b[0] - a[0];
    let dy = b[1] - a[1];
    let rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    return this.toBearing(rotation);
}